# Merge result after for function

Tags: matlab

Good morning everybody

I work to develop mathematical model to solve one of the industrial engineering problem but I have a problem in the write of the MATLAB code. So I simplified this problem in the following code. I need to merge all the result of X in one matrix after the for function used to use it in the next step (in this simple case this matrix will be 40*3)

```
LIST=randi([0,1],[4,3]);

for i = 1:10
    j=i

V=randi([0,1],[4,3]);

for m = 1:4
for n = 1:2
    if V(m,n)== 1;
       X(m,n) = LIST(m,n);
    elseif V(m,n)== 0;
       X(m,n) = 2;
end
end
end

for m = 1:4
for n = 3
    if V(m,n)== 1;
       X(m,n) = LIST(m,n);
    elseif V(m,n)== 0;
       X(m,n) = 3;
    end
end
end

X
end
```

Thank you for your time and your consideration

Answer (score 0):

At each iteration of the outer loop (`for i = 1:10`) the values in the `X` matrix are overwritten.

In order to store all the values you need to increment the row value of the `X` matrix of the value of max limit of the second loop (`for m = 1:4`) that is `4`.

You can do it by modifying the indexing of the `X` matrix as follows:

```
X(m+(i-1)*4,n)
```

You can make your script more "general" by identifying the limit evaluating it as the number of rows in the `LIST` matrix using the function [size](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) function:

```
[n_row,n_col]=size(LIST)
```

In this way

- at the first iteration of the outer loop, the row index will range from `1` to `4`.
- at the second iteration itr will range from `1+(2-1)*4` to `4+(2-1)*4` that is from `5` to `8`
- and so on

This is the updated code

```
LIST=randi([0,1],[4,3]);
[n_row,n_col]=size(LIST)

for i = 1:10
   j=i
   V=randi([0,1],[4,3]);
%    for m = 1:4
   for m = 1:n_row
      for n = 1:2
         if V(m,n)== 1;
%             X(m,n) = LIST(m,n);
            X(m+(i-1)*n_row,n) = LIST(m,n);
         elseif V(m,n)== 0;
%             X(m,n) = 2
            X(m+(i-1)*n_row,n) = 2;
         end
      end
   end
%    for m = 1:4
   for m = 1:n_row
      for n = 3
         if V(m,n)== 1;
%             X(m,n) = LIST(m,n)
            X(m+(i-1)*n_row,n) = LIST(m,n);
         elseif V(m,n)== 0;
%             X(m,n) = 3;
            X(m+(i-1)*n_row,n) = 3;
         end
      end
   end
   X
end
```

Hope this helps.

Qapla'

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer it is very helpful and I used the modified model in my case but only one change in X function the correct is X (m+(i-2)*n_row,n) = 3;

Comment: I do not understand your comment: if you use `X(m+(i-2)*n_row,n) = 3;`, depending of the value of `V(m.n)` you could get either an invalid index (0 or a negative one). E. g. first iteration of the outer loop `(i=1)`, `m=1` ==> `X(1+(1-2)*4,n)` ==> `X(-3,n)`. Another cases, e. g. `i=1`and `m=4` ==> `X(0,n)`. You should get an error such as _Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals_